# Why does pip redownload the same package for another venv with a different python version?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, conda, python-venv

I have two virtual environments. One has python 3.7.9. the other had 3.8.5. I have downloaded torch 1.6.0 in the 1st virtual env. But when trying to install the same torch version in the second virtual env, it downloads the entire package again instead of installing from cache.

Is there any way to force download from cache as I want the same torch==1.6.0 in both the environments and its frustrating to download it everytime.

Comment: It appears that torch has [different library versions for different Python versions](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#modal-close). You literally cannot use the same version for both environments.

Comment: If a library contains C extensions (and pytorch does), these are usually compatible with one major Python version only (thus the ABI tag `cp37-cp37m` etc). If a library uses only the limited API part (defined in [PEP 384](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/)), the wheel may declare compatibility between different major versions (denoted usually by defining the minimal supported version and upwards in the ABI tag, e.g. `cp36-abi3`), but pytorch isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the listed files...

https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files

There are different wheels for different Python versions.

This makes sense, as eg the syntax changes between Python versions.